# Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. SQL/Python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

genre1, genre2, genre3 has data being retrieved from select fields on my web page. When I select two genres (two fields) it adds the movie perfectly fine. But when I select all three genres (all fields) it gives me an error.

It just doesnt work when theres (genre1,genre2,genre3)
It does work when its (genre1,genre3)..but I need all three ofcourse

"Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type."

```
for name in (genre1, genre2, genre3):
  if name != "":

    genreInfo = db.execute(
        """
        SELECT Genre_ID
        FROM Genres
        WHERE Genre = ?; 
        """,
        (name,)
        )
    selectedGenre = genreInfo.fetchone()[0]

    db.execute(
        """
        INSERT INTO Movie_Genre (Movie_ID, Genre_ID)
        VALUES (?,?)
        """,
        (MovieID, int(selectedGenre),)
        )
    db.commit()
  else:
    pass
    flash("Movie Added!")
    return render_template('admin.html', user_name=user_name, genre=genre)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full traceback and the value causing the error. You have two queries with parameters; we have no way of knowing which one fails.

Comment: Thats all I have, i did not know what was causing the error either. Moving 'db.commit()' outside the for loop fixed the issue..

Comment: Python gives you a traceback. The title of this question is the last line. We need everything before it, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.. So I moved "db.commit()" so that its outside the for loop and it worked.. I do not know why so if anyone would like to explain.. please feel free to!